# Help to understand this phrase?

Tags: word-choice, meaning

作者首先提到了中国 媒体对于西方世界民主制度的一贯批判手法

The writer first mentions that the Chinese media have always been critical of one thing in the Western World’s democracies.

I don't get "一贯批判手法."  I suppose it means the last part of the English translation, but I don't get it.

Comment: 一贯批判手法 ＂unswerving technique of criticism＂ ～ persistent criticism
 iciba：手法：skill ； technique ； trick ； gimmick ； ploy
一贯：from beginning to end ； unswerving ； consistent ； persistent ； all along

Answer (score 3):

Some issues with your translation:

- `一贯（的）` means `typical/consistent`, not `one thing`. In this sentence, `一贯批判手法` could be translated as `typical/consistent criticism`
- The original sentence focused on the criticism itself instead of the phenomenon of "the Chinese media being critical of democracies"

IMHO, a better translation would be,

> The writer first mentions **typical criticism of** the Chinese media on the Western World’s democracies.

Answer (score 1):

一贯=typical, 批判=critical, 手法=method. I think "one thing" is not a correct translation for 一贯, 一贯 should be considered as whole.